# Error: Cannot connect to [Microsoft][ODBC Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: java, database, ms-access

It's been a while since i last came here. Please i'd like you guys to help me look at this code.I have a package called timetabling_system.TTGS and within the main package,which is timetabling_system.TTGS,is another folder called resources where a database designed with Microsoft access is located.i am trying to connect my java app with it but i can't.Have tried all i could but to no avail.Checked online and all i got was that access has issues with 64-bit systems, mine is also 64-bit and i have this app to present at school before Thursday. All is well with the app,the only problem is the db connection which is actually the gateway to the main app.i have embedded the code for this here so that professional eyes can look into it and tell me where i went wrong.

```
package timetabling_system.TTGS.Login;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;

public class LOGIN {
String url, url1, to;
String from = getClass().getResource("/timetabling_system/resources/TTGS.mdb").toString();
String error;
String hd = System.getenv("HOMEDRIVE");
String hp = System.getenv("HOMEPATH");
String tp = hd + hp;
File db;
boolean PASSF, USERF, userVal = false;

public LOGIN() {
db = new File(tp + "/Local Settings/Temp/TTGS");
if (!db.isDirectory())
if (db.mkdir()) {/* System.out.println("Created..."); */
}
if (from.contains("jar:")) {
url1 = from;
url1 = url1.substring(6 + 4);
url1 = url1.replaceAll("%20", " ");
url1 = url1.substring(0, url1.indexOf("!"));
CopyFile();
} else {
url1 = from;
url1 = url1.substring(6);
url1 = url1.replaceAll("%20", " ");
url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ="
+ url1;
}
error = "";
}

public void CopyFile() {
File fo = new File(db.getPath() + "/TTGS.mdb");
OutputStream fos;
try {
JarFile jf = new JarFile(url1);
JarEntry je = jf.getJarEntry("timetabling_system/resources/TTGS.mdb");
InputStream ins = jf.getInputStream(je);
fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fo));
int eof = 0;
eof = ins.read();
while (eof != -1) {
fos.write(eof);
//System.out.println("b:" + eof);
eof = ins.read();
}
//System.out.println(" eof:" + eof);
ins.close();
fos.close();
from = fo.getPath();
// System.out.println(from);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
url1 = from;
url1 = url1.replaceAll("%20", " ");
url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" + url1;
}

public User CHECK(User luser) {
User user = new User();
try {
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
String eks = "SELECT * FROM LOGIN";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(eks);
while (rs.next()) {
user.setUserName(rs.getString("LOGINNAME"));
user.setPassword(rs.getString("PASSWORD"));
user.setName(rs.getString("NAME"));
user.setType(rs.getString("TYPE"));

if (luser.getUserName().equals(user.getUserName())) {
USERF = true;// user name is right
if (luser.getPassword().equals(user.getPassword())) {
PASSF = true;// user password is right
break;
} else {
PASSF = false;// user password is wrong
break;
                }
} else
USERF = false;// user name is wrong
        }
stmt.close();
con.close();
if (PASSF == true && USERF == true) {
error = "Welcome to TTGS >> " + user.getName() + " : " + user.getType();
userVal = true;
return user;
} else {
error = "Sorry try again ! ";
return user;
}
} catch (ClassNotFoundException cls) {
error = "Error >> " + "Cannot Find Driver";
} catch (SQLException ql) {
PASSF = false;
USERF = false;
error = "Error >> " + ql.getErrorCode() + " : " + ql.getMessage();
}
return null;
}

public boolean isValid() {
return userVal;
}

public String getMsg() {
return error;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application cannot find the Jet driver via

```
url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ="
+ url1;
```

then it must be running as 64-bit. There is no 64-bit Jet driver, so you'll need to download and install the 64-bit version of the Access Database Engine from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255), and then use this instead:

```
url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ="
+ url1;
```